# SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData seems to deadlock

Tags: object-model, splistitemcollection, multithreading

I'm trying out multithreading with the SP2010 Object Model and I've run into some weirdness.

My application currently does the following:

1. Opens an `SPSite` and uses `AllWebs.WebsInfo` to build a `Guid[]` of the IDs of all the webs in the site.
2. Creates e.g. 10 threads. Each thread:

   1. Opens the same `SPSite`
   2. Gets the next web ID in a thread-safe manner that's not causing any trouble.
   3. Opens that `SPWeb`.
   4. Gets a particular list from it.
   5. Tries to iterate through the items.
   6. When done, gets the next ID, or finishes if there are none left.

At step `2.5.`, all of my threads hang. It's at the point where they're causing `EnsureListItemsData` to be called ten times near-simultaneously, on separate lists, and it seems to break.

However, if between steps `1.` and `2.` I cause `EnsureListItemsData` to be called, for example by calling `site.RootWeb.Lists["MyList"].Items.Count`, *everything is fine*. The problem only arises when the ten simultaneous calls *are the first calls to `EnsureListItemsData` in the process*.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? I don't understand why it's locking up, and thus don't trust my "fix" to be reliable.

Here's a shortened program that exhibits the same problem. The threads just call `Items.Count` rather than trying to iterate. The line that causes the problem to go away is commented out.

```
class Program {
    static Guid[] webIDs;
    static int currentIndex;

    static Guid? NextWebID { 
        get {
            int index = Interlocked.Increment(ref currentIndex);
            if (index < webIDs.Length) return webIDs[index];
            return null;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        currentIndex = -1;
        using (var site = new SPSite("http://portal")) {
            webIDs = site.AllWebs.WebsInfo.Select(wi => wi.Id).ToArray();
            //var i = site.RootWeb.Lists["Pages"].Items.Count;
        }

        var threads = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new Thread(Work)).ToArray();
        threads.All(t => { t.Start(); return true; });
        threads.All(t => { t.Join(); return true; });
    }

    static void Work() {
        using (var site = new SPSite("http://portal")) {
            Guid? webID = null;
            while ((webID = NextWebID).HasValue) {
                using (var web = site.OpenWeb(webID.Value)) {
                    var i = web.Lists["Pages"].Items.Count;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am theorising but EnsureListsData is making sure the list is in the current context, you are running on a separate thread, so I presume it doesn't have context access until this is run?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - what do you mean by the current context? This is just a console app so `SPContext.Current` is null throughout.

Comment: Well in this case it would be making sure that the thread is running in the context of the SPWeb you are supplying, it's the only part of EnsureListItemsData that seems to do anything that would affect the process.